# Set Array member to null instead of ""

Tags: javascript, null

How can we set empty strings inside an array to `null` in JavaScript?

My array:

```
var myarray = [["01.01.2013","a"],["01.02.2013","b"],["01.03.2013",""]]
```

I need to replace the second value in the third element to `null`.

My attempt was to check whether a string is empty and then set it to `null` but that results in `"null"` and not `null`.

Comment: Out of curiosity... why? Besides that, how are you outputting the result?

Comment: Show your attempt so that we can explain what you did wrong.

Comment: I plot the result. I need the null in order to detect missing points and break the graph for them (jqplot).

Comment: I tried myarray[2][1] = myarray.replace('', null);

Comment: that surprises me that you would get a `"null"` result from that since an Array doesn't have a `.replace()` method.

Comment: tried and errored. one of my results as the "null" string. quite chaotic programming over here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
myarray = myarray.map(function(el) {
  return el.map(function(v) {
    return v === '' ? null : v;
  });
});
```

... but I'd rather do it with a simple check, without generating tons of new arrays.

```
myarray.forEach(function(arr) {
  if (arr[0] === '') arr[0] = null;
  if (arr[1] === '') arr[1] = null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to detect empty strings, you don't need to set anything to `null` since [code inside `if ("")` does not execute](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/#if-statement). Just check like this: `if (string) { /* string is not empty */ }`.

Otherwise, if you really need the element to be `null`, what's wrong with just assigning it? For example:

```
> myarray[2][1] = null;
> console.log(myarray[2]);
["01.03.2013", null]
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 (currently negligible browser support):

```
myarray = myarray.map(i => i.map(i => i==='' ? null : i))
```

IN ES5:

```
myarray = myarray.map(function(i){
    return i.map(function(i){
        return i==='' ? null : i;
    })
})
```